# Internal frames hang outside the main window when using SwingWorker

Tags: java, swing, vtk

I am a beginner in Java Swing, and encounter a question that I don't know why it happened. 
I want to show multiple internal frames of 3D image in a desktop pane and do this in another thread, so I am using **SwingWorker**. Those frames are loaded in the desktop pane but also hang outside the window.

[[image: Please see the picture here.]

The images are rendered by VTK, so I don't know if it is the problem of **SwingWorker** or mixing of heavyweight/lightweight components.

Here is the code for swingworker (internalFrameWorker.java)

```
public class internalFrameWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, ShowPLY>{
    private String[] files;
    private int x, y;
    private DropFilePane parent;
    private boolean done;
    private ShowPLY plyframe;

// Constructor
public internalFrameWorker(String[] filenames, int posx, int posy, DropFilePane pane) {
    this.files = filenames;
    this.x = posx;
    this.y = posy;
    this.parent = pane;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

    for(String fn: files){
        plyframe = new ShowPLY(x, y, fn); // ShowPLY outputs a JInternalFrame
        plyframe.pack();
        plyframe.setVisible(true);
        parent.add(plyframe);
        x += 20;
        y += 20;
    }
    return null;

}
```

}

Any help will be appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: *" mixing of heavyweight/lightweight components."* is always a bad idea, but they tend to produce graphical glitches. But since heavyweight components also have an independent paint cycle, they could cause other issues.  Also, from within your `SwingWorker`, you should not be modifying the state of the UI from within the `doInBackground` method, but instead, using `publish` to push the updates to the UI via the `process` method